# Scripting Operators - Any way to make it shorter?

Tags: scripting

I'm not a newbie when it comes to scripting but I always wondered!
Let's say I want to check if "num" equals to 2 or equal to 4, 6 and 8.

```
if(num == 2 || num == 4 || num == 6 || num == 8)
```

But, is there any way to make it shorter? Something like

```
if(num == 2 || 4 || 6 || 8)
```

I know it doesn't work, but I'm just wondering.
Would be cool to learn something.

EDIT:
The above numbers are used for example. Math formulas won't do the work for me since I'd actually want to compare between "num" and variable names.

Comment: Scripting in what language?

Comment: It's basically same for most of them, C, C#, PHP, Pawn, Squirrel and such.

Comment: It was an example. Not these values specifically. Let's say variable names?

Comment: I think (using Perl as my knowledge base) you can use `if ((2||4||6||8) == num)` with the `or` parts on the left hand side of the `==` specifically. But this is off the top of my head, so I'd recommend trying it

Comment: Since this question doesn't specify a language, I think it should be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can do:

```
if (in_array($num, array(2, 4, 6, 8)) !== false) {
}
```

In jQuery you can do:

```
if ($.inArray(num, new Array(2, 4, 6, 8))) {
}
```

If such a function is not offered by language X, then you can write a function to loop through and do the checks until one succeeds, and then exit the loop with true, else return false.

Comment: Ignore the undeclared downvote folks, I think I angered a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)! I've been cracking down a bit on 'em recently.